# @RequestMapping Spring MVC3 Receiving 404 error with path variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am farely new to Spring and Java.  I have a controller where I have 3 functions all using path variables; however the one function is returning 404 resource not available when passing the path variable.

Am I missing something obvious here?  Below is the controller and any help is much appreciated.  The third one is the one that is not working.

```
@RequestMapping("/Request")
@Controller
public class RequestController {

    @Autowired
    SnowService snowService;

    @Autowired
    DBService dbService;

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String request(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws HttpException, IOException {
        return snowService.getRequest(id,"true");
    }


    @RequestMapping("/myRequests/{active}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String myRequest(@RequestHeader("iv-user") String id, @PathVariable("active") String active) throws HttpException, IOException {

        Person me = dbService.getById(id);
        String snow_id = me.getSnow_id();
        return snowService.getRequest(snow_id,active);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/myItems/{sys_id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String myItems(@PathVariable("sys_id") String sys_id) throws HttpException, IOException {

        return snowService.getItems(sys_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: paste here address you trying to reach and it returns 404 error, maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: It is an intranet site, so it is not able to be accessed from outside our network... but this is the url I am using.  https://mycompanyintranetapp.com/SrvPrtl/Request/myItems/197b69266fd451000865ee7cbb3ee447

Comment: hmm, mapping itself looks good (often mistake is to forget to add "s" to item(s) and something like that)...

Comment: webapp logs might help the diagnostic

Comment: Good point, I will check them out now.

Comment: The logs seem to indicate that the last thing isnt being mapped.  Any ideas?  Below is what the logs show (missing the miItems mapping)

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Request/myRequests/{active}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String

Comment: Are you sending the request with a different method (POST instead of GET) or maybe with some different headers than the request (maybe Accept set to application/json or something)?

Comment: @CodeChimp That wouldn't cause a 404. In any case, their `@RequestMapping` doesn't restrict the `method` so all HTTP methods are handled.

Comment: Can you include all the logs that are generated on request in the original question?  Are the other two mappings are working ok if you try to access those? I assume SrvPrtl is the application name (e.g. the root of the app)

Comment: SrvPrtl was the root of the app.  I was able to resolve this and I believe it had something to do with eclipse on my new computer, it wasn't building the project correctly I assume.  Once I switched back to my old computer and exported the war file with the same code it worked fine.